# Google Street View API v3 : how can I avoid having "fish-eye" effect on Firefox? (fisheye effect)

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, google-api, google-street-view

I'm using google maps API V3 and I'm having trouble displaying correctly the street view within Firefox. I always get the "fish-eye" view (does not happen with Google chrome).

So I assumed that the problem came from Firefox.

I took a look to the street view options but found nothing.

I would like to know if there is an option to have a flatten street view or if it is because Firefox does not support this kind of feature.

If someone could explain it to me, I would be grateful.

Below, what it looks in Firefox :

[image: Optical "deformation" in Firefox]

And what it looks in Chrome :

[image: Nothings wrong with Chrome]

Since a week I'm working on this project, I found no solution. Even the smallest suggestion/idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it's not about you and you cannot fix this issue.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a moz-xxx property introducing this problem. When I display the view in another way, eg. in an iframe (passing thru Drupal), all is OK. I'm very skeptical with with this tricky "bug", since I don't understand nor find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a kind of answer :

*French forum, sorry* - See this : [http://www.developpez.net](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1094371/webmasters-developpement-web/javascript/bibliotheques-frameworks/apis-google/differences-streetview-v2-v3-fish-eye/)

It seems that V3 is in trouble with that, using specific Chrome/Safari APIs or something like that.

With the V2, all is OK.

We tested with IE8/9, Opera, Chrome, FF and Safari, and only Chrome & Safari render it correctly.

I will complete this "post" if the project is continued and more information gathered.

EDIT

See this [Google Issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4041) entitled "Provide an API to report when Street View has HTML4 fisheye", which explains that this is a HTML5 to HTML4 renderisation problem.

So, there is no solution to this problem except using only specific browsers or using only V2, which is what we will do here.

Thanks to all who looked at this question, if you find something different, tell it here to help those who need it :)

Comment: Sorry but this project is not anymore under my "review", then I will probably never have the answer.